# Disk issues without symptoms: Undertanding dmesg report and assessing the risk

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

We have a Cassandra Cluster of 10 nodes, four of which show some disks errors as reported by `dmesg`. Those reports keep showing up more or less every hour.

The disk reported in the errors is the half of an 8TB logical volume -the other disk seem not be reporting errors.

```
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sas: Enter sas_scsi_recover_host busy: 1 failed: 1
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sas: ata7: end_device-0:0: cmd error handler
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sas: ata7: end_device-0:0: dev error handler
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sas: ata8: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: cmd 25/00:08:10:d8:5d/00:00:84:01:00/e0 tag 8 dma 4096 in
         res 51/40:00:10:d8:5d/00:00:84:01:00/e0 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: error: { UNC }
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 84 5d d8 10 00 00 00 08 00 00
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6515709968
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7: EH complete
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sas: --- Exit sas_scsi_recover_host: busy: 0 failed: 1 tries: 1
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] ata7.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

An `iostat -xdct 1 100` shows very reasonable numbers for R/W rates and average queue sizes:

```
grep "^sda" iostat-xdct | awk '{n+=1; r+=$6; w+=$7; qsz+=$9; qmx=qmx<$9?$9:qmx; qmi=qmi>$9?$9:qmi}END{printf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t\t[%.3f , %.3f]\n",r/n,w/n,qsz/n,qmi,qmx)}'

818.239 6.939   0.038           [0.000 , 0.890]
```

According to all our usual metrics, the system is working fine. However, I'm concerned this may lead to a fatal system error at the most unexpected time.

I have no clue what the error reported means. Even less do I know how to assess the risk involved in keeping the system running like this. Should I change disks immediately?

I will paste here the output of smartctl -a /dev/sda:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB
Serial Number:    S6BBNJ0R700321V
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 f31706f50
Firmware Version: SVT01B6Q
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   Unknown(0x09fc), ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.2 (0x1ff), 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 28 12:58:46 2022 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 320) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   068   068   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1510
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       9429
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       11
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   068   068   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1510
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   068   068   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1510
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       8242
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   068   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       8242
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       35415578583

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 8242 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 8242 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9429 hours (392 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 10 d8 5d e0  Error:

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------

Error 8241 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9428 hours (392 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 d7 5d e0  Error:

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------

Error 8240 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9427 hours (392 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 d7 5d e0  Error:

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------

Error 8239 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9427 hours (392 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 d7 5d e0  Error:

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------

Error 8238 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9426 hours (392 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 d7 5d e0  Error:

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  256        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: You've not mentioned what "errors" you see in `dmesg` -- without that, I'm not sure how anyone can judge what the situation is :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown Totally right. Jus added it.

Comment: MASL that doesn't look good at all. Please run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` as soon as you can (as root), and add the results to your question. You may have a dying disk that's also run out of reallocatable sectors. **Make sure your backups are current**.

Comment: @roaima How can I upload a file?

Comment: @roaima Ok I pasted the result of smartctl you asked directly in my question. Thanks

Comment: Check your disk with samsung magician desktop utility. How much TBytes are written? SMART numbers is not standartized and real sector size is unknown. And compare this one with smart of other disks of same model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very poorly disk. See here:

```
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 84 5d d8 10 00 00 00 08 00 00
[Wed Sep 28 12:29:02 2022] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6515709968
```

This is telling you that the OS couldn't read data from the disk.

See here:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   068   068   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1510
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       9429
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
```

The disk has been running for about 13 months (assuming 24x7, which is plausible with only 6 power cycles recorded). Unfortunately 1510 reallocated sectors is about 1505 more than I'd be happy with.

Here we can see that there are an awful lot of failed disk reads:

```
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   068   068   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1510
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       8242

195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       8242
```

You've written a fair number of blocks (potentially 131 TB) but nothing extraordinary (SSDs have an guaranteed upper write expectation over their lifetime, and yours is 2400 TB) and certainly not out of proportion:

```
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       35415578583
```

I'm a little concerned that the OS sees the disk as having 512B sectors; they should be 4kB sectors/blocks. It might be worth checking this with tools like `fdisk` or `parted` to see if it's a fault in `smartctl`.

In conclusion, I would say it's time for a new disk. Seeing as it's died after 13 months I would have assumed there was a 12 month warranty, but it appears the EVOs have five years.

---

In the comments the OP asked, "*Are this relocations a way for the disk to keep working despite hw issues, like writing off sectors? Why is `iostat` still showing all normal?*".

If a disk sector/block can't be read you'll get an error at the the OS level. Typically it'll end up as an IO error when trying to read (edit, copy, backup) a file. The disk will mark the sector/block as unreadable and the uncorrectable count will increase. When the OS (or application) writes data to that sector/block on the disk the firmware will take the opportunity to remap the sector/block to one of its spare sectors/blocks that are reserved for this very purpose. The uncorrectable count may decrease and the reallocated count will increase.

So far the disk firmware has managed to reallocate 1510 sectors/blocks, and mostly most IO is fine (which is why `iostat` seems ok). Every so often you'll hit another unreadable sector/block - as shown in `dmesg`, and this won't go away until you try to write to it. Sooner or later the disk will run out of its reserved sectors/blocks and you'll get a cascade of write errors followed by a broken filesystem. This really isn't a place you want to be, so I would recommend you try to replace the disk under warranty.

Regardless, **make sure you have - and continue to take - good backups**.

Comment: https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/internal-ssd/870evo/ MZ-77E4T0 (4,000GB) 5 Years or 2,400 TBW vs 146TB written from smart is a lot?   (assume 4K sector even with 512B reported by smart)

Comment: 1 year runtime is a lot? Just 1500 bad sectors is bad but is a lot?

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is here, @gapsf. There have been a considerable number of relocated blocks/sectors/whatever and the OS is _still_ having access errors. (I know blocks are only relocated on write, but each one potentially represents lost data.) I warranty my NAS HDDs after just a few reallocations.

Comment: @roaima As you sure noticed my understanding of disks internals is poor. Are this relocations a way for the disk to keep working despite hw issues, like writing off sectors? Why is iostat still showing all normal? I know I didn't asks for explanation for what's going on. Would be helpfull though in escalating the issue. Thanks in advance.